# Can play gif image on main page on UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gif

I see lots of SNS Apps like google plus, sina weibo, they don't play gif at main page (usually main page is news feed page, like Facebook's), some of them play gif image manually, some of them don't play gif image just show first frame of gif image.

I wondered why they don't play gif image on main page? For performance? For style thinking? Or  forbidden by Apple?

Answer (score 0):

You can load an animated gif by loading gif into NSData then,

```
[self.webView loadData:gifData MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my question is why they don't play on main page, some of apps need you click the gif image on main page (just show the gif image first frame on main page) then you need to play gif manually say: click "play gif" button. Some of them just don't play gif, even you click the gif on main page (just show the gif image first frame on main page) and an image detail page pops up and still show you the gif's first frame